# Pretty Permalinks not working - Resulting in 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, buddypress, ubuntu-15.04

I just install [Buddypress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/installation/) to my existing Wordpress site in localhost on ubuntu 15.04.However buddypress need to change the permalinks to other than the default permalink. i just change it to

> /%sample-post%/

whatever the permaink i choose its give me the same error

> The requested URL /ocpasl/issuses/ was not found on this
>   server.Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

this is my .htaccess file.

```
 #BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ocpasl/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ocpasl/index.php [L]
</IfModule> 
 #END WordPress
```

what would be the problem. and how do i fix this.?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly AllowOverride All is not set in your apache config file, you can enable it by editing vhosts or apache config(httpd.conf) file.

here is a sample configuration

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change

> AllowOverride None

to

> AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

for those using nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: If you are using .htaccess, you are not using nginx.  This answer doesn't seem relevant for the question.